# Finding if the Point is in the triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Can You Please tell me if this is right

Point(x,y,z) triangle points ABC

using co-planer 
determinant

|x-Ax y-Ay z-Az|
|x-Bx y-By z-Bz| = 0
|x-Cx y-Cy z-Cz|

then the point is in the tringle

Comment: Your question is not clear, please write it clearly.

Comment: Dou you want to know if the sentence:

Comment: P is on the interior of $\triangle ABC$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$\begin {array}{|c c c|}
(x-x_A) & (y-y_A) & (z-z_A)\\
(x-x_B) & (y-y_B) & (z-z_B)\\
(x-x_C) & (y-y_C) & (z-z_C)\\
\end {array} =0$ is true?

Comment: Hi thanks Abhra Abir Kundu . YES is it true?